# WordPress on Xampp has it's .htaccess file outside xampp's installation folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have a site I am currently developing using WordPress on localhost with xampp. Yesterday during some tests, I accidentally changed site's URL from `http://localhost/testsite` to `http://localhost`, that might have messed up something inside xampp's project management system, because I immediately lost access to my site. I was able to fix it by manually changing back the site and homepage URLs in the database, but then I found something weird happening.

Let's say my testsite web is located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\testsite`. So now, I have an `.htaccess` file in `C:\`, and if I delete it, all my pages now except homepage return **404**. I can restore the file going to **Settings->Permalinks** and saving changes, but the `.htaccess` file this operation generates still shows up in `C:\` folder instead of `C:\xampp\htdocs\testsite`.

Is there any way to tell xampp where to look for that `.htaccess` file or should I just backup my db and website files, and reinstall xampp, and, if so, what steps should I follow to ensure not missing anything important that might cause trouble later on?

Comment: "I accidentally changed site's URL" - You must have done something more than this. This alone would not have done anything to the server config. However, you appear to have changed something in the server config to enable `.htaccess` files to be processed in C:\ (the filesystem root) - Apache isn't normally (and should not be) set up to do this by default. Apache looks for `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path that the URL-path maps to (only if it is permitted to do so). There's something wrong in the WordPress config if it's writing to `C:\.htaccess`.

Comment: If I changed anything else, it was not explicitly, I mean, I only changed the url within the admin panel in WordPress, and then the two rows in the db for site url and homepage url as I saw in a couple of tutorials. Maybe changing that url specifically to just localhost, where xampp might be handling apache server and some other softwares, might have indirectly caused some internal file update leading to that path change, but that's the closest my guess can get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I ended up backing up my db and theme, completely uninstalling and installing xampp again, then installing WordPress, adding my saved theme, importing the db, and regenerating the .htaccess file within the permalink section in settings, it now works fine and the file is where it's supposed to be.

I'm pretty sure there was an easier and faster way to do this, but I couldn't find it and this worked anyway.